# How to import a file from the folder that my .py script is being called from?

Tags: python

I'm currently working on a python package that I want to upload to pypi.

In the future, other devs will install this package via `pip install` and then load it into their .py files using `import name_of_package`.

In order to function properly, my python package needs to import another .py file from the same folder that it was imported into.

So let's assume someone works in `/documents/python/some_project/` and he imports my package into his `main.py` script. My package script shall then search for a file called `secondary.py` in the same folder where `main.py` is located, namely `/documents/python/some_project/` and then import `secondary.py` into the package script.

How can I write this import statement in my package script?

Comment: Why is this file not included within your package?

Comment: Because it will be different for every user. The user can define some styles in `secondary.py`, which my package needs to import then, in order to work properly.

Comment: Your should take a look at how [django handles user settings](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/conf/__init__.py#L171), it's a bit complicated but essentially the user must set an environment variable which corresponds to their local settings file which django can import and use itself.

Answer (score 0):

The classic approach is to use relative imports;

```py
from .other_module import foo_function
from .other_module import BarClass
```

See [The import statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#import) in the Python doc.

You can also take a look at [importlib.import_module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module).

But, in your specific case, you want to call an external Python script located potentially anywhere in the user directory.

For that, you can use [exec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) function. But, make sur the code your are calling is safe code.

When you use `pip install`, the installed package is stored in the [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) of the user; not in the user’s source directory. I think you are also confused by that.

Comment: If I use a relative import in the package script then it will try to do a relative import based on where it's installed on the user's system, correct? So there is no hard-coded way to do a relative import from the package installation path to the project path, because the project path will always differ from user to user. Do I get something wrong here?